# Is it possible to write code that no IDE is able to parse?

Tags: c++

Today I wanted to try an opengl wrapper called [oglplus](http://oglplus.org/html/index.html). I am able to use the library but my IDE is throwing tons of errors messages at me. I tried it with QtCreator and EclipseCDT.

Basically no IDE is able to see the members/methods of various classes. So I did some digging. For example the class `FragmentShader` has atleast two methods called Source and Compile.

Eclipse and QtCreator are showing me the following source code.

```
#if OGLPLUS_DOCUMENTATION_ONLY
    /// Fragment shader wrapper
    /**
     *  @see Shader
     *  @see Program
     *  @ingroup objects
     */
    class FragmentShader
     : public Shader
    { };
    #elif GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER
    typedef Specialized<
        Shader,
        OGLPLUS_CONST_ENUM_VALUE(ShaderType::Fragment),
        SpecializedShaderInitializer
    > FragmentShader;
    #endif
```

So okay probably every shader is exactly the same, just named differently.

```
class Shader
 : public ShaderOps
{
public:
    Shader(ShaderType type);
    Shader(ShaderType type, String description);
};
```

It seems that ShaderOps is the important class.

I also found the method 'Source' in ShaderOps (it is in the public block)

```
const ShaderOps& Source(
        const GLchar** srcs,
        const GLint* lens,
        int count
    ) const
    {
        assert(_name != 0);
        OGLPLUS_GLFUNC(ShaderSource)(_name, count, srcs, lens);
        return *this;
    }
```

Do you have any idea why *no* IDE is able to see these methods? Is there something weird in the source code?

Is it even possible to write code that is so different that IDE's have trouble to parse it?

Ps: I have only tested it with eclipse cdt and Qtcreator.

Comment: IDEs will not parse, Compilers will.

Comment: So it is the job of the compiler to tell the IDE what methods/members a class has?

Comment: Yes, actually it depends, usually IDEs use compilers or something like that to parse the code. However, maybe some rare IDEs do it themselves.

Comment: @MM. I would challenge that assumption. For compiling/running, yes, delegating is the most sane option. But IDEs require far more much -- enumerating and searching members and types, finding references, etc. are things no compiler needs, but the IDE needs and and it needs to do it incrementally (whereas compilers usually bulk-load). Add to that the fact that most compilers' frontends are hard to impossible to use from other programs, and it's no surprise that most IDEs contain their own parsers.

Comment: The IDE will most likely run the c preprocessor and then inspect the code after that. If it doesn't understand the macros in the code, then it will probably get things wrong. I have certainly seen this in Eclipse before now. Typically, it can be fixed by fiddling with either settings for "what defines" or the code itself, but it can require a bit of experimenting to get it right. If the code is part of a third party library or some such, and your IDE is a major one (such as Eclipse), then I'd complain to the third party saying "Please fix your code so that it can be understood by eclips".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason may be ifdef guards: `#if OGLPLUS_DOCUMENTATION_ONLY`

If you do not define preprocessors properly, IDE will not show related class/methods